# How to get value of radio buttons from one html page to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I try to get the value of the at the bottom pasted html code who stands on the first html page. I have another html page, which should be generated with the button "onclick". More precisely the code should create buttons in the next page.

**Case1:** radio-choice-1 is selected - it should create 4 buttons.

**Case2:** radio-choice-2 is selected - it should create 4 or 9 buttons.

**Case3:** radio-choice-3 is selected - it should create 9 or 16 buttons.

**Case4:** radio-choice-4 is selected - it should create 16 buttons.

**I dont know how to get the value of the selected radio buttons then generate buttons on another page.**

I actually have a bit of script(game.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#radio-button-value').click(function(){
        $("input[name='radio-button-gruppe']:checked".val());
    });
});
```

first html page

```
     <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>newgame</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Einstellungen zur Defintion als WebApp -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <script src="game.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>


    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
  <legend>Choose a mode:</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked">
  <label for="radio-choice-1">easy</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2">
  <label for="radio-choice-2">medium</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3">
  <label for="radio-choice-3">difficult</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4">
  <label for="radio-choice-4">hard</label>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" id="radio-button-value" name="game" value="create game" class="button" data-theme="b"/>
</form>





  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">

  </div>
</div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use cookies as the question below suggests. That's what cookies are for. Storing bits of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what sort of solution you're looking for.  But if you don't want to use something more deeply rooted, like the $_SESSION variable in php, you're probably looking for something like cookies.  [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)'s a great page on cookies.

Also check out [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111) tutorial from htmlgoodies.com on variable passing with javascript for some other ideas.

If you're okay with cookies, you can pretty much use what you already have, just clean up the jquery a little.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#radio-button-value').click(function(){
        var difficulty = $("input[name='radio-choice']:checked").val();
        document.cookie = "gameDifficulty=" + difficulty + ";path=/";
    });
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fukaL87y/)

Comment: when I make it with an session in php, how can I set the value and later get the value?