# How to transfer radio button selection from 1html to another without php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to transfer radio button data from the first html to the second with Pure JavaScript `Its ok if you use some jQuery`.

[jQuery used](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js)

**1st HTML**

```html
<body>
<label for="1">
<input type="radio" name="num" id="1" checked="checked" value="1" >1
</label>
<label for="2">
<input type="radio" name="num" id="2" value="2" >2
</label>
<label for="3" >
<input type="radio" name="num" id="3" value="3" >3
</label>
<label for="4">
<input type="radio" name="num" id="4" value="4" >4
</label>
<button onclick="saveSession()">save</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveSession(){
// I want to save the value of the radio button to sessionStorage here
}
</script>
</body>
```

In my second HTML I would like to retrieve this data and set the value of the radio buttons to the same.

**2nd HTML**

```html
<body onload="type()">
<label for="1">
<input type="radio" name="num" id="1" checked="checked" value="1" >1
</label>
<label for="2">
<input type="radio" name="num" id="2" value="2" >2
</label>
<label for="3" >
<input type="radio" name="num" id="3" value="3" >3
</label>
<label for="4">
<input type="radio" name="num" id="4" value="4" >4
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
function type(){
//I want to get the data with sessionStorage.getItem()
}
</script>
</body>
```

> It would be better if you can also tell me how to disable the form

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!!

Comment: If your html files are on the same domain, then you can use the local storage of the browser.

Comment: This could help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630468/how-to-get-value-of-radio-buttons-from-one-html-page-to-another

Comment: Yes local storage has worked for a text input but I don't know how to use it on a radio button/check box.

Comment: To access the radio button value, since you're using jQuery, try this: $('input[name="num"]:checked').val();

Comment: How do I use it in my js?

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem("num", $('input[name="num"]:checked').val());  and then to retrieve it, sessionStorage.getItem("num");

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same for checkboxes? @Andrew_CSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comments as an answer. To access the radio button value, since you're using jQuery, try this:

```
$('input[name="num"]:checked').val();
```

On the first HTML page,

```
sessionStorage.setItem("num", $('input[name="num"]:checked').val());
```

And then on the second page,

```
 sessionStorage.getItem("num");
```

or, to set the value of the radio on the 2nd page with the stored value:

```
$('input[name="num"]').val([sessionStorage.getItem("num")]);
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8or3chye/

Comment: The reason it wasn't working is that I forgot to link jquery to the 2nd page I had linked it only to the first page.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same for checkboxes? @Andrew_CSE

Comment: It's going to be a similar process. Checkboxes aren't grouped like radio buttons, but you can simulate a group by adding a common name to them, and then using that name as part of the selector. Here's a fiddle showing some of the things you can do with that, and similar to your radio button scenario, I included saving/retrieving from browser storage. https://jsfiddle.net/wa1Lfvoz/

Comment: Just for the sake of it, and for comparison, here is the same checkbox fiddle using pure JS without jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/0mb42xou/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a change event handler to your radios and save a new value to the local storage on that event. Afterwards on page load you need to read the saved value of the radio from the local storage and if it exists - you find an element by id and set checked to true

```html
<label for="1">
    <input type="radio" name="num" id="1" value="1" onclick="handleClick(this);" >1
</label>
<label for="2">
    <input type="radio" name="num" id="2" value="2" onclick="handleClick(this);" >2
</label>
<label for="3" >
    <input type="radio" name="num" id="3" value="3" onclick="handleClick(this);" >3
</label>
<label for="4">
    <input type="radio" name="num" id="4" value="4" onclick="handleClick(this);" >4
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleClick(radio) {
        localStorage.setItem('numRadio', radio.value)
    }

    (function() {
        const radioValue = localStorage.getItem('numRadio')
        if(radioValue) {
            const targetRadio = document.getElementById(radioValue)
            targetRadio.checked = true
        }
    })()
</script>
```